# Difference between 赤｛あか｝ and 赤色｛あかいろ｝

Tags: words

What is the difference between  赤｛あか} and 赤色｛あかいろ｝？

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3418/9831

Answer (score 0):

赤色 is just a redundant form of 赤

赤 also has other meanings besides just red, so 赤色 can be used to clarify you're talking about the color red in a confusing situation.

An example in English would be:

> the curtains are red

versus

> the curtains are of red color