# Using adjectives in simple sentence (Need です and い-form?)

Tags: adjectives

I meet various sentences with adjectives, which version is correct?

> この猫{ねこ}は黒{くろ}です。 (...kuro desu)
>
> この猫は黒いです。
>
> この猫は黒い。

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3418/7810

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which version is correct?
>   この猫は黒です.
>   この猫は黒いです.
>   この猫は黒い.

All three are grammatically correct.
The 黒 in the 1st sentence is a noun, and the 2nd and 3rd are using an i-adjective 黒い. The です in the 2nd sentence is a polite suffix.

> I meet various sentences with adjectives,

We have two kinds of adjectives, i-adjectives and na-adjectives, which basically function as a predicate this way:

> この猫は**かわいい**。-- plain form
>   この猫は**かわいいです**。-- polite form
>   (かわいい = i-adjective)
>   この花は**きれいだ**。-- plain form
>   この花は**きれいです**。-- polite form
>   (きれい = na-adjective)

---

Note that Japanese words for colors, such as 黒, 赤, 緑, 紫, 黄色 etc. are nouns and can be followed by the copula だ / です, like this:

> この猫は**黒です**。-- polite form
>   この猫は**黒だ**。-- plain form

The 6 colors 黒, 白, 赤, 青, 茶色, 黄色 have i-adjective alternatives 黒い, 白い, 赤い, 青い, 茶色い, 黄色い, which can be used this way:

> この猫は**黒いです**。-- polite form
>   この猫は**黒い**。-- plain form

<sub>incorrect: ×「緑い(です)」 ×「灰色い(です)」</sub>

---

As a side note: Only a few words can fit in both 「～～だ/です」 and 「～～い(です)」:

> やわらかだ/やわらかい
>   あたたかだ/あたたかい
>   [真]{ま}っ[白]{しろ}だ/真っ白い
>   [真]{ま}っ[黒]{くろ}だ/真っ黒い
>   四角だ/四角い
>   丸だ*/丸い <sub>(*丸 is a noun, not a na-adjective, so you can't say 丸な~~.)</sub>

For example, you can say:

> このパンは**やわらかいです**。このパンは**やわらかい**。(やわらかい = i-adjective)
>   このパンは**やわらかです**。このパンは**やわらかだ**。(やわらか = na-adjective)

For more on this topic, see: [i-adjectives used as na-adjectives: is there a difference? (e.g. 大きい versus 大きな)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1853/9831)

Answer (score 4):

> 1. この猫は黒です。
> 2. この猫は黒いです。
> 3. この猫は黒い。

If you want to say "this is a black cat", sentence 2 and 3 are possible answers, and the sentence 2 sounds polite.

By the way, the sentence 1 also makes sense, but it has another interpretation that "the name of this cat is *kuro*".
 If you want to avoid this kind of mis-interpretation, you could say like この猫は黒色です, but this expression sounds a little bit academic or high-flown, so I would not recommend you to use it in daily conversations.