# japanese adjectives

Tags: grammar, usage, adjectives

```
赤のボウル 
赤ワイン 
赤いセーター
```

What is the rule here?
When do i use の particle, when i use nothing and when do i make い adjective(if i understand it correctly)
Someone explain please.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3418/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46396/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36047/9831

Comment: To put it simply, use no if you are connecting two nouns, a i-adj does not need anything else to modify a noun, and if you use nothing it would have to be a set phrase/compound word. If it is not then use the other two.

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question.

Comment: This explains the difference between 赤ワイン (red wine) and the other two, but not why it is 赤のボウル but 赤いセーター; could it be 赤いボウル but 赤のセーター? What would be the difference?

Comment: @JohnFrazer apparently の is used when there is more than one variant of this thing.
Like if you buying in store blue but not red bowl. い is just for general usage and wont be a mistake. As i've been told.